# LibTorrent delay downloading a piece

Tags: libtorrent

I'm using libtorrent 1.2.1 and I have a torrent with several pieces set to don't download (priority 0).

The problem is that after setting the piece priority to top_download (priority 7) there is a delay of 60 seconds before the download starts.

How can I force the download to immediatly start after setting the piece priority?

Answer (score 0):

to know what's going on, you need to enable logging (by setting the [alert_mask](https://libtorrent.org/reference-Settings.html#alert_mask)). Probably both `peer_log_notification` and `torrent_log_notification` (see [docs](https://libtorrent.org/reference-Alerts.html#alert)). This will post alerts about what's going on.

For example, once all your non-zero priority pieces have been downloaded, all seeds are disconnected. If you don't have any peers by the time you set piece priorities, it may take a while to reconnect new peers.

There are a fair number of [configuration knobs](https://libtorrent.org/reference-Settings.html#settings_pack) to adjust this behaviour. It's hard to diagnose what's happening in your case specifically without more information though.

Comment: Setting close_redundant_connections to false solved the problem. Thank you.